# Why IR receiver at gadget not take the hex code?

Tags: esp8266

I have an IR remote for a gadget, I am decoding the values using esp8266 Arduino library

i get,

Protocol: UNKNOWN

Code      : 0xD8396229 (129 Bits)

uint16_t rawData[257] =
 {
536, 966,  544, 462,  506, 998,  512, 490,  516, 488,  544, 962,  514, 490,  516, 988,  514, 490,  512, 972,  530, 476,  530, 972,  510, 996,  514, 492,  512, 974,  532, 492,  512, 492,  510, 494,  510, 492,  544, 462,  506, 498,  528, 478,  530, 496,  510, 494,  508, 494,  508, 496,  544, 462,  524, 480,  526, 480,  526, 498,  508, 496,  506, 496,  508, 496,  544, 462,  542, 464,  524, 480,  526, 498,  506, 498,  506, 498,  508, 496,  540, 466,  542, 462,  522, 482,  524, 482,  524, 498,  504, 500,  504, 500,  504, 500,  542, 962,  506, 980,  526, 484,  520, 500,  504, 500,  504, 500,  506, 500,  542, 462,  546, 460,  546, 460,  522, 502,  502, 500,  504, 502,  502, 502,  508, 498,  544, 462,  544, 460,  546, 954,  542, 464,  544, 462,  546, 460,  562, 484,  504, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  504, 500,  542, 464,  546, 460,  544, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  504, 500,  540, 466,  542, 464,  546, 460,  544, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  526, 480,  506, 500,  540, 466,  544, 462,  544, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  502, 502,  506, 498,  540, 466,  544, 462,  544, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  504, 502,  538, 466,  542, 464,  544, 462,  542, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  526, 478,  506, 500,  538, 466,  544, 462,  542, 480,  524, 480,  524, 480,  524, 480,  504, 502,  506, 498,  540, 466,  544, 464,  542, 958,  508, 500,  544, 462,  542, 480,  524, 480,  524, 480,  524};  // UNKNOWN D8396229

the same "raw data" is sent to gadget using an IR transmitter LED, its receive well.

but when i send the hex code(0xD8396229) using different

protocol defines in the library(ESP8266IRremote-master), it does not work.
Why does this happen?

protocol tested,

irsend.sendNEC(0x00D8396229);

irsend.sendSony(0x00D8396229, 129, 2);

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just send as raw data then. As the printouts tell you, protocol is unknown and data contains 129 bits. Neither Sony nor NEC protocols use 129 bits, and even if they could be customized to send 129 bits, they would be the wrong protocols for sending the bits. 129 bits do not fit into a 32-bit integer either, so D8396229 can't possibly contain the whole 129 bits of data you need to send, even if you could write the correct bit sending protocol.